# ghost charge during checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have this issue with some customers when they checkout where there is a ghost charge in their account. It seems like there is a product in their cart from a previous session that is no longer visible in their cart. The only way that I have been able to get around this is to process a test order from their account to "flush" it and then the "ghost" charge goes away. I'm not sure what to call it.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I would really appreciate some advice because I'm sure customers may feel like we are trying to trick them or over-charge them, but this isn't the case. It would be helpful to be able to "flush" their cart without having to login by changing their password or asking them to do this process first before they can order what they want. It's pretty inconvenient.

Comment: Do you have access to the DB? If so, I'd check the sales_flat_quote table, find the active quote in questions' id and then reference that ID to the sales_flat_quote_items table and look to see if there is a rogue item on the quote that you didn't add to the cart.

Comment: Thanks Rob!! I will check this next time the issue arises and post back here to update! 
In the meantime, any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: Do you have any custom logic or extensions relating to modification of the quote ?

Comment: No I don't. Can you suggest something for me?

Comment: Next thought, just thinking if this is your problem.   If a user adds items to their cart, begins the checkout process and chooses to login, if they had items in their cart the previous time.  These quotes would merge and the customer may not notice this until it's to late

Comment: I looked up a current customers cart to make sure they had items in it. Searched sales_flat_quote by their email and found the latest quote. I copied the ID and searched the sales_flat_quote_item table for that quote ID, but the products in the list and the products in the cart are completely different. :/
Is there any extension you know of that would help to modify a quote?
Also, if the products merge from  before and after login, wouldn't they all still be visible?

Comment: Ok so the issue came up with another customer, and I figured out how to remove the items that shouldn't be there.

What would be the best way to insure that customers don't have this issue. Is it safe to truncate Sales_flat_quote tables? Will this clear data for customers order history?